# Pause all threads while resource is being worked on

Tags: python, multithreading

At the if statement inside `process_data()` how do I pause all other threads when the condition is met, wait until the work on the `insert_list` is done, and then resume them again?

```
import threading
import logging
import queue


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='[%(levelname)s] (%(threadName)-10s) %(message)s')


def process_data(data, insert_list):
    while True:
        item = data.get()
        logging.debug(f'Working on: {item}.')

        if item is None:
            break

        insert_list.append(item)

        if len(insert_list) == 2:
            logging.debug(f'Committing: {insert_list}')
            insert_list = []

        data.task_done()


num_workers = 4
insert_list = []
data = queue.Queue()
threads = []

for i in range(num_workers):
    t = threading.Thread(target=process_data, args=(data, insert_list))
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for n in range(1,11):
    data.put(n)

data.join()

for i in range(num_workers):
    data.put(None)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

What I'd like to see is something like this:

```
[DEBUG] (Thread-1  ) Working on: 1.
[DEBUG] (Thread-2  ) Working on: 2.
[DEBUG] (Thread-2  ) Committing: [1, 2]
[DEBUG] (Thread-1  ) Working on: 6.
[DEBUG] (Thread-4  ) Working on: 4.
[DEBUG] (Thread-4  ) Committing: [6, 4]
etc...
```

For context I'm trying to use threads to speed up loading of a large amount of data in text files to a database. I'm using the threads to extract the data and add it to a list shared by all threads. When the list reaches a certain size I'll take the list and commit its items to the db (doesn't support concurrent inserts) while I want the other threads to pause adding new items to the list, wait for the list to be processed, then resume. I'm not worried about the order the data is processed in, just that the threads stop adding new items to the list until the list is ready again.

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you want a [blocking queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html) that makes a thread wait if the queue is "full".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe standard Queue with defined maxsize for `insert_list` would be a better decision, not sure:

```py
insert_list = Queue(max_size=2)

def process_data(data, insert_list):
    while True:
        item = data.get()
        logging.debug(f'Working on: {item}.')

        if item is None:
            break

        insert_list.put(item)

        if insert_list.full():
            i_list = [insert_list.get() for _ in range(insert_list.qsize())]
            logging.debug(f'Committing: {i_list}')

        data.task_done()
```

Comment: Your alternative worked a treat. The queue was the way to go. Thanks.